# How to efficiently group terms in sympy for lambdafication?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy polynomial that has a gazillion terms.  I want to lambdify that formula.  However, since it has a gazillion terms, and the polynomial is expanded, there are more operations going down than are optimal.  Specifically, by *grouping* certain terms together, we can eliminate a number of operations.  Consider the following equation, for example:

```
x^2y^2 + x^2y + x^2 + 1
```

If I lambdify this, then, if `x` and `y` are 1D `np.array`s of length N, there will be 4 element-wise square-ings, 2 element-wise multiplications, and 3 element-wise additions, resulting in approximately 9*N operations.

OTOH, by doing a little algebra, we arrive at:

```
x^2(y^2 + y + 1) + 1
```

By a parity of reasoning, this formula only involves 6*N operations.  If I have a larger and more complex formula, the difference could be quite large.

In any case, I don't need to find the representation that *maximizes* the performance, but it is clear that a little grouping of terms would at least *improve* performance.

How can I do this sort of "term grouping" to achieve a more efficient representation of my `sympy` formulae when lambdafying?

Comment: Note that `sympy.factor` does nothing to my example equation up above.  I need something more powerful than `sympy.factor`.

Answer (score 2):

You might group terms by symbols in common and use `horner` on them:

```
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for t in Add.make_args(eq):
...  d[tuple(ordered(t.free_symbols))].append(t)
...
>>> Add(*[horner(Add(*i)) for i in d.values()])
x**2*y*(y + 1) + x**2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `sympy.collect`.  If the equation doesn't have too many variables, it's possible to simply brute force all combinations, and to recurse down into the "collected" terms.

Here's the code I came up with.  There's probably room for a lot of improvement:

```
def collect_best(expr, measure=sympy.count_ops):
    # This method performs sympy.collect over all permutations of the free variables, and returns the best collection
    best = expr
    best_score = measure(expr)
    perms = itertools.permutations(expr.free_symbols)
    permlen = np.math.factorial(len(expr.free_symbols))
    print(permlen)
    for i, perm in enumerate(perms):
        if (permlen > 1000) and not (i%int(permlen/100)):
            print(i)
        collected = sympy.collect(expr, perm)
        if measure(collected) < best_score:
            best_score = measure(collected)
            best = collected
    return best

def product(args):
    arg = next(args)
    try:
        return arg*product(args)
    except:
        return arg

def rcollect_best(expr, measure=sympy.count_ops):
    # This method performs collect_best recursively on the collected terms
    best = collect_best(expr, measure)
    best_score = measure(best)
    if expr == best:
        return best
    if isinstance(best, sympy.Mul):
        return product(map(rcollect_best, best.args))
    if isinstance(best, sympy.Add):
        return sum(map(rcollect_best, best.args))
```

`rcollect_best` turns this (count_ops = 136):

```
4*a**3*d*e - 6*a**2*b*d*e - 6*a**2*c*d*e + 16*a**2*e**3 + 6*a**2*e*f**2 + 6*a**2*e*g**2 + 2*a*b**2*d*e + 8*a*b*c*d*e - 14*a*b*e**3 - 2*a*b*e*f**2 - 8*a*b*e*g**2 + 2*a*c**2*d*e - 14*a*c*e**3 - 8*a*c*e*f**2 - 2*a*c*e*g**2 - 2*b**2*c*d*e + 2*b**2*e**3 + 2*b**2*e*g**2 - 2*b*c**2*d*e + 8*b*c*e**3 + 2*b*c*e*f**2 + 2*b*c*e*g**2 + 2*c**2*e**3 + 2*c**2*e*f**2
```

Into this (count_ops = 68):

```
2*e*(d*(2*a**3 - 3*a**2*b + a*b**2 + c**2*(a - b) + c*(-3*a**2 + 4*a*b - b**2)) + e**2*(8*a**2 - 7*a*b + b**2 + c**2 + c*(-7*a + 4*b)) + f**2*(3*a**2 - a*b + c**2 + c*(-4*a + b)) + g**2*(3*a**2 - 4*a*b + b**2 + c*(-a + b)))
```

Which is a 5th degree polynomial in 7 variables.  Run-time is about 10 or 15 minutes, and will increase super-exponentially, so I don't recommend this for anything much more demanding than this.  I'm sure there are some basic improvements that could fix the super-exponential growth, but this has solved my problem, so I'm cashing out now.  :)